# How to check for a condition before executing MYSQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I am trying to check to see if a condition exists before executing a mysql update. This code below WORKS:

```
if (!mysql_query(
"UPDATE customers SET available_credit = available_credit where userid = '$userid';"
))

{
die('Sorry, a database error occurred');
}
```

...but I'm trying to add another condition to it like this:

```
if (!mysql_query && ($tradein_status == 'Accepted CREDIT')(
"UPDATE customers SET available_credit = available_credit where userid = '$userid';"
))

{
die('Sorry, a database error occurred');
}
```

..which DOESN'T work - it generates this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in /home/bohemeth/public_html/tradeins/save_tradeins.php on line 235"

The second thing I am wondering is why is this part:

```
if (!mysql_query(
"UPDATE customers SET available_credit = available_credit where userid = '$userid';"
))
```

...not written with two parens and curly braces after the condition, which it seems you would do anywhere else for a conditional test, like so:

```
if (!mysql_query){
"UPDATE customers SET available_credit = available_credit where userid = '$userid';"
}
```

THANK you for any help!!

Comment: You can never have this: `if (!mysql_query &&`. `mysql_query()` is a function.

Comment: Thanks Nick.. what would be the better way to write things then? Do I wrap the statement that DOES work with an outer if statement?  Like:     if ($tradein_status == 'Accepted CREDIT') {  if (!mysql_query(
"UPDATE customers SET available_credit = available_credit where userid = '$userid';"
)) }

Comment: http://php.net/if ; http://php.net/expressions ; http://php.net/operators --- it's all in the PHP language reference at the beginning of the manual. I suggest to at least skim the reference once and read cross it.

Comment: I've re-worded the question to hopefully make it less localized, since the question was closed for being too localized.   Since the question is really how to test a condition (such as the contents of a variable or a flag or whatever you want) before executing the MySQL query, it seems broadly applicable to me... Thanks.  - Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_query` is a function.  It's used like this: `mysql_query('SQL QUERY');`

It was written like in your question as an attempt to make it more readable:

```
if(!mysql_query(
'SQL QUERY'
))
```

It could also be written this way:

```
if(!mysql_query('SQL QUERY'))
```

So, to add another clause, add it before or after the `mysql_query` call.

```
if($tradein_status == 'Accepted CREDIT' && mysql_query('SQL QUERY'))
```

In an `if` statement the `{}` can be omitted.  In that case, the very next line is the one ran if the case is true.

So, to finalize:

```
if($tradein_status == 'Accepted CREDIT' && mysql_query('SQL QUERY')){
    die('Sorry, a database error occurred');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($tradein_status == 'Accepted CREDIT' && !mysql_query (
"UPDATE customers SET available_credit = available_credit where userid = '$userid';"
))

{
die('Sorry, a database error occurred');
}
```

mysql_query is a function, not a variable.  The string in the second parens is the argument.

Comment: Oh duh. I see.. that's the answer to the second part of my question too... I get it. I'll try that. THANKS guys.    UPDATE - Yep it works. THANKS!

Comment: Wish I could select your answer too, since it totally works, but I had to select the first guy I guess.

Comment: No problem man... I'll just have to learn to type faster!  Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($tradein_status == 'Accepted CREDIT')
    mysql_query("UPDATE customers SET available_credit = available_credit where userid = '$userid';") or die("Sorry, a database error occurred");
```

You cannot write other code between the function name and the arguments.

Comment: I see. THANK you for your help bwoebi!  Your solution, like the others above also works great!

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` is a function call, which passes your query `"UPDATE customers SET available_credit = available_credit where userid = '$userid';"` as a string parameter.

This means that `mysql_query` must be of the form:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE customers SET available_credit = available_credit where userid = '$userid';")
```

mysql_query returns a RESOURCE.. which is the result of your query.

In order to add a second conditional statement, do this:

```
if (!mysql_query("UPDATE customers SET available_credit = available_credit where userid = '$userid';") && ($tradein_status == 'Accepted CREDIT'))
```

Comment: Thank you Justin! Another excellent solution to my newb issue. Appreciated.